# Создание массива кнопок

Tags: python, tkinter

Необходимо создать массив кнопок и для каждой определить действие (изменить кнопку). Однако после создания на нажатие реагирует лишь последний элемент в матрице.

```
from tkinter import *

def changeBut(event, button):
    #что-то сделать с кнопкой

root = Tk()

for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        but = Button(root, borderwidth = 0)
        but["text"] = str(i) + "_" + str(j)
        but.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: changeBut(event, but))
        but.grid(row = i, column = j)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: похожий вопрос: [Why results of map() and list comprehension are different?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/139819/4279)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проблема в том, что в Python функция обращается за значением переменной не в момент её создания, а в момент вызова.

В вашем случае все созданные через lambda функции будут получать одно и то же значение `but` -- последнее.

Для того, чтобы так не происходило, стоит явно связать нужное значение, используя аргумент по умолчанию:

```
but.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, but=but: changeBut(event, but))
```

После этого ваша функция будет работать так, как от неё ожидается.

---

Эту же проблему можно продемонстрировать на более простом примере. Пусть мы хотим создать список функций, которые возвращают квадраты чисел от 0 до 4. Воспользуемся генератором списков (или циклом, не важно):

```
functions = [lambda: i * i for  i in range(5)]
```

Теперь у нас есть список из пяти функций. Попробуем их выполнить:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(functions[i](), end=' ')
```

Выведет `16 16 16 16 16` вместо ожидаемых `0 1 4 9 16`.

Для того, чтобы получить ожидаемое поведение, нужно явно передавать нужное значение:

```
functions = [lambda i=i: i * i for  i in range(5)]
```

---

Для того, чтобы разобраться в том, почему так происходит, нужно понимать, как происходит поиск значения в Python. Сначала значение переменной смотрится в локальном пространстве имён, затем в том, в которое он вложен и так далее до объектов из встроенного пространства имён.