# Вывод текста из кнопки

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Помогите вывести текст из кнопок которые формируются благодаря массиву пример кода описан ниже. Если есть возможность привязать к кнопку `id` как это делается с радиокнопками то можете описать как это сделать потому что когда я пытался у меня вообще ничего не выдавало и вылетало приложения после нажатия на кнопку 3.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
def buttin():
    def openbase():
        f=namebase.text()
        print(f)# по идеи должен выводится текст кнопки, но т.к. последнее название кнопки было 3, он любую кнопку будет выводить 3
    global v
    h=[1,2,3,4]
    for b in range(len(h)):
        print(v)
        namebase= 'btn'+str(b)
        namebase = QPushButton(str(b), root )
        namebase.resize(50,30)
        namebase.clicked.connect(openbase)
        namebase.move(10,v)
        v=v+50
v=10
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
root= QWidget()
root.setFixedSize(700,700)
buttin()
root.setWindowTitle('QSplitter')
root.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: у вас та же проблема что и в [Создание массива кнопок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/478561/23044)

Comment: @jfs да я осознал свою проблемму

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def buttin():
    def openbase(f):
        binds = main.root.button_group.id(f)
        print(binds)
    global v,l
    h=[1,2,3,4]
    main.root.button_group = QButtonGroup()
    for b in range(len(h)):
        namebase = QPushButton(h[l], main.topleft )
        namebase.resize(90,30)
        namebase.move(30,v)
        v=v+50
        main.root.button_group.addButton(namebase, l)
        l=l+1
        main.root.button_group.buttonClicked.connect(openbase)
v=20
l=0
```