# Создаю в цикле чекбоксы, затем в другом цикле нужно взять значения этих чекбоксов, но берётся всегда последний

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import IntVar
from tkinter import BOTH
from ttkthemes import ThemedTk
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

headers = {'accept': '*/*',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) \
             Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0'}
URL = 'http://m.myscore.ru/'

league_data = []

data = ["/volleyball/", "/others", "/", "/?s=1&amp;event=refresh_button", \
 "/tennis/", "/american-football/", "/baseball/", "/rugby/", "/handball/", "/basketball/", "/hockey/", "/?s=1&event=refresh_button"]
urls_1 = []
urls_2 = []
urls_3 = []

c = []


class Scrollable(tk.Frame):
    """
       Make a frame scrollable with scrollbar on the right.
       After adding or removing widgets to the scrollable frame,
       call the update() method to refresh the scrollable area.
    """

    def __init__(self, frame, width=16):

        scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(frame, width=width)
        scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y, expand=False)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(frame, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        self.canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        scrollbar.config(command=self.canvas.yview)

        self.canvas.bind('<Configure>', self.__fill_canvas)

        # base class initialization
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, frame)

        # assign this obj (the inner frame) to the windows item of the canvas
        self.windows_item = self.canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=self, anchor=tk.NW)

    def __fill_canvas(self, event):
        "Enlarge the windows item to the canvas width"

        canvas_width = event.width
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.windows_item, width=canvas_width)

    def update(self):
        "Update the canvas and the scrollregion"

        self.update_idletasks()
        self.canvas.config(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox(self.windows_item))


def chk_btn_click():
    soup = bs(requests.content, 'lxml')

    # Контейнер в котором хранятся наши элементы

    print(cbtn.cget('text'))
    div = soup.find('div', id="score-data")

    leagues = div.find('h4', text=cbtn.cget('text'))
    urls_1 = leagues.find_all_next('a')

    try:
        leagues_n = leagues.find_next('h4')
        urls_2 = leagues_n.find_all_previous('a')
    except:
        pass

    try:
        urls = list(set(urls_1) & set(urls_2))
    except:
        urls = urls_1

    for url in urls:
        url = url.get('href')
        urls_3.append(url)

    for i in urls_3:
        if i in data:
            continue
        else:
            c.append(i)
    print(c)


def get_league():
    for lg in league_data:
        print(cbtn_state)


root = ThemedTk(theme='arc')
root.geometry('500x400+300+200')
root.resizable(0, 0)

top_frame = ttk.Frame(root)
top_frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.5, relheight=0.1, anchor='n')

button = ttk.Button(top_frame, text='Получить список лиг', command=get_league)
button.place(relx=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
lower_frame = ttk.Frame(root)
lower_frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.25, relwidth=0.9, relheight=0.6, anchor='n')

scroll_frame = Scrollable(lower_frame)


global requests
session = requests.Session()  # иллюзия непрерывности во времени
requests = session.get(URL, headers=headers)  # эмулируем открытие

soup = bs(requests.content, 'lxml')

div = soup.find('div', id='score-data')  # Контейнер в котором хранятся наши элементы

leagues = div.find_all('h4')  # Находим все лиги
for league in leagues:
    league = league.text
    league_data.append(league)
    cbtn_state = IntVar()
    cbtn = ttk.Checkbutton(scroll_frame, text=league, variable=cbtn_state, command=chk_btn_click)
    cbtn.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)


scroll_frame.update()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Создание массива кнопок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/478561/Создание-массива-кнопок)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем обработчике изменения состояния Checkbutton:

```
def chk_btn_click():
    soup = bs(requests.content, 'lxml')

    # Контейнер в котором хранятся наши элементы

    print(cbtn.cget('text'))
    ...
```

`cbtn` - это не конкретный `Checkbutton`, который сейчас изменил состояние, а то что лежит в глобальной переменной `cbtn` - то есть последнее, что туда положили в цикле инициализации (последний созданный `Checkbutton`).

Аналогично здесь:

```
def get_league():
    for lg in league_data:
        print(cbtn_state)
```

Вы не проходите по состояниям всех чекбоксов, а выводите одну и ту же объект-переменную (даже не ее значение, а сам объект), то что записали последним в глобальную переменную `cbtn_state`.

Исправляем цикл инициализации:

```
leagues = div.find_all('h4')  # Находим все лиги
cbtn_states = []
for league in leagues:
    league = league.text
    league_data.append(league)
    cbtn_state = IntVar()
    cbtn_states.append(cbtn_state)  # все привязанные переменные сохраняем в список
    cbtn = ttk.Checkbutton(scroll_frame, text=league, variable=cbtn_state)
    # Делаем, чтобы при нажатии в обработчик передавался сам виджет:
    cbtn.config(command=lambda widget=cbtn: chk_btn_click(widget))
    cbtn.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)
```

Исправляем обработчик изменения состояния:

```
def chk_btn_click(wiget):
    soup = bs(requests.content, 'lxml')

    # Контейнер в котором хранятся наши элементы

    print(wiget.cget('text'))
    ...
```

Исправляем отображение состояний для каждой лиги:

```
def get_league():
    for lg, var in zip(league_data, cbtn_states):
        print(lg, var.get())
```

Comment: премного благодарен за столь подробный ответ, вот только теперь появилась ошибка cbtn.config['command'] = lambda widget=cbtn: chk_btn_click(widget)
TypeError: 'method' object does not support item assignment

Comment: @АртемЛантратов, поправил, попробуйте теперь.